# How can we redirect a Java program console output to multiple files?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can we redirect the eclipse console output to a file? I can:

1. `Run Configuration`->`Commons`->`Select a file`.
2. Use `System.setOut(PrintStream)` and `System.setErr(PrintStream)`.

The problem with 1) is that I need to record console output to different files instead of one file.

The problem with 2) is that it only stores console output generated by `System.out.println()` or stacktrace of an exception thrown. It does not capture other kind of outputs e.g. log4j warnings etc.

How can we redirect console output to different files programmatically?

Comment: 1) Maybe you shoude be use "Variables.." (ex) C:\test${???:??}.txt

Comment: Here's an idea. Write your own eclipse plugin (ie., a cusotm button) which would assign a random but unique value to a variable (called `${NAME}`), then would do the same thing as run. Then use `$NAME` as the value for the output file. maybe?

Answer (score 176):

Go to run as and choose `Run Configurations` -> `Common` and in the Standard Input and Output you can choose a File also.

Comment: I find it absolutely hilarious that 40 people upvoted a copy-paste from the second line of the question.

Comment: @AnthonyW I think that's mostly because people are led here by the title question which is "How can we redirect eclipse output to a file". This answer is in fact an answer to the title question.

Comment: If you can't find "Run Configurations", using Eclipse 4.4 (Luna), I opened my Launch Configuration (by double clicking on the server in the Servers tab), clicked on "Open lanuch configuration", then went to the Common tab.  In the bottom half of that dialog, there is a section called "Standard Input and Output".  Here, I could click on File and give it a file name.

Comment: Hint: open a terminal, `echo $TTY` and specify whatever it returns as your file. Then the terminal will mirror what is in your Eclipse console.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Then why don't you edit the answer and add how you can do it on Luna as well

Comment: What? This answer is incorrect when reading the questioner's question carefully.

Answer (score 11):

You could use a "variable" inside the output filename, for example:

```
/tmp/FetchBlock-${current_date}.txt
```

current_date:

> Returns the current system time formatted as yyyyMMdd_HHmm. An optional argument can be used to provide alternative formatting.  The argument must be valid pattern for java.util.SimpleDateFormat.

Or you can also use a system_property or an env_var to specify something dynamic (either one needs to be specified as arguments)

Answer (score 8):

You can set the output of System.out programmatically by doing:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/location/to/console.out")), true));
```

Edit:

Due to the fact that this solution is based on a `PrintStream`, we can enable autoFlush, but according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29):

> autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the output buffer will be flushed
>   whenever a byte array is written, one of the println methods is
>   invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written

So if a new line isn't written, remember to `System.out.flush()` manually.

(Thanks Robert Tupelo-Schneck)

Comment: It seems that you also need to close with `System.out.flush()` in order to avoid possibly missing some output.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem I use ${string_prompt} variable.
It shows a input dialog when application runs. I can set the date/time manually at that dialog.

1. Move cursor at the end of file path.
   [image]
2. Click variables and select **string_prompt**
   [image]
3. Select Apply and Run
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by setting out variable of System class in the following way

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Path to output file"))). Also You need to close or flush 'out'(System.out.close() or System.out.flush()) variable so that you don't end up missing some output.

Source : http://xmodulo.com/how-to-save-console-output-to-file-in-eclipse.html