# Separate stdin and stdout file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, stdout, stdin

The launch configuration dialog is

[image]

Am I right that if one needs the input from a file then output also goes into a file? Why it must be the same file? I do not see any option to have two separate connections.

Answer (score 0):

The UI is admittedly confusing, but the file will only be used for *output*.  There's no similar way to use a file as input, thus the "necessary for input" hint.

See:

[I/O redirection in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799277/701303)

[Eclipse reading stdin (System.in) from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/188547/701303)

[How can we redirect eclipse console output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5714053/701303)