# Can't redirect the output of system()

Tags: c

I'm running an executable in Linux in the terminal like so:

`./foo 1 2 3 >output.txt`

The results are not outputted to output.txt, even though the file is created but doing `&>output.txt` instead does the trick. So I guess the response of ./foo is defined as stderr??

But moving on.. my objective is to call that ./foo program within C multiple times but I'm not managing to get the output to a file when I do this:

`status=system("./foo 1 2 3 &>output.txt")`

The output only appears in the Eclipse console but the file is indeed created but remains empty. (I also tried `>` only)

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to give information about what command interpreter or shell you are using - the way `system()` calls work varies depending on those (which is consistent with the effect of `system()` being implementation defined).   However, assuming you are on a unix system, you will be better off using `fork()` and one of the `exec()` family of functions to execute your program.   If you do that, an approach for redirecting output is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605130/redirecting-exec-output-to-a-buffer-or-file

Comment: It's a program not done by me to simulate a LIDAR camera. It returns something like this:
` LIDAR 
   Minimum = 0.000000 radians, maximum  = 2 radians`

Comment: That's irrelevant, actually.   `system()` typically launches a local shell which, in turn, executes your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here: [How can we redirect a Java program console output to multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714053/how-can-we-redirect-eclipse-console-output-to-a-file)

The problem was that the eclipse console was "stealing" the output.