# I want to save eclipse console log into a string

Tags: java, eclipse, console, logfile, system.out

I just need to save Eclipse's Console/Terminal content into a string or a file. I have researched a lot on this issue and what I only got is how set up the Logger to print on a file, which is not what I want. 
What I want exactly is to print the content of the eclipse console with what ever it has (exceptions, anything that I printed to, Warnings.... etc)
[image]

Comment: The simplest (and most common) solution is to use a logging API, if that's not what you want (questions will get asked), you could redirect the System.out to where ever you want

Comment: [This is an example of the basic idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea/12945678#12945678)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we redirect a Java program console output to multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714053/how-can-we-redirect-a-java-program-console-output-to-multiple-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect console output to file in run configuration settings on the "Common" tab.

[image]